Why is charging super slow under Ubuntu on a MacBook Air 2017?
After replacing macOS with Ubuntu on my MacBook Air 2017, I'm experiencing extremely slow charging speeds that I never had before.
After an hour of charging the battery went from 4% to 8%, and in power settings it predicts 23 hours until fully charged from there. Is there any way to improve this without going back to macOS?

Update: After restarting, the battery shows up much higher. It seems there was an issue with correctly reading the charge level, which I would still like to resolve if possible.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
